# Loading controllers in angular single page application

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading, loading, single-page-application, controllers

I am developing a small SPA with AngularJS. I have followed the best practices described in [Adnan Kukic](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure) post for directory structure.
The application includes around 10 different controllers and the index file looks clean thanks to the use of routing and partials. The only problem I have is that I have including all controller files in the header section of the index file like:

```
<script src="app/components/home/homeController.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/blog/blogController.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/detail/detailController.js"></script>
```

I'm sure there is a better way of including these script files. Should I necessarily use a module loader like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) for this or is there a more simple solution?
By the way, because of the small size of the application, I don't care if the solution addresses lazy-loading or not.

Comment: I always load with requirejs for my angular apps. It is an artifact of our legacy project and I have grown to appreciate the organization it provides.

Comment: I think most SPAs involve a build step using a tool like Grunt or Gulp that concatenates and minifies all the JS files into a single script. It's more useful in debug to keep things separate, but when moving to production a single file is ideal.

Comment: I agree with you about the build step. My question is more about the development phase.

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject for example.